# Is there a way to manipulate the result of an mongo db aggregate query to return single object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a simple aggregate mongo db query which gives me expected result.

```
db.getCollection('parts-status').aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$partStatus" ,count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "Unauthorized",
    "count" : 2.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "Authorized",
    "count" : 12.0
}
```

But i want my result in this format :

```
{
"Unauthorized": 2.0,
"Authorized": 12.0
}
```

Is it possible to manipulate the initial result of aggregate to get the desired result within in the query itself??

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
 db.getCollection('parts-status').aggregate([
 { 
   $group: {
     _id: "$partStatus" ,
     count:{$sum:1}
   }
 },
 {
   $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [[{k: "$_id", v: "$count"}]]
        }
    }
  }])
```